# using monitor to solve consumer/producer

Tags: synchronization, monitor, notify, consumer, producer

In the common pattern of solving consumer/producer problem with monitor, why is notify/notifyall statement used always even though it makes sense to use it only when number of elements in array changes from zero to one or from n to n-1. In the way how it's described in almost all literature, it ends up that significantly big percentage of notify calls end up having zero effect which implies just wasting resources. Or I am missing something big here?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is easier to write that pattern like that than to check array every time. Furthermore, notify all does not waste resources. I think, it should be same thing to make if statement by yourself as calling notify/notifyAll when no thread is waiting for signal. I guess, optimization is made under the hood.